# Moving a repository from git to github on a different username

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a separate git account for university and personal use. For a recently completed university project, I made a git repository on my student account and added commits as I went on. Now, I wish to create a new repository for the project on my personal GitHub account, and transfer all the data (commits, source code etc) from the completed repository on my student git account to this personal GitHub account.

How can I move all the data from a git repository to a GitHub repository, when the git repository is on a different username from the GitHub one?

PS Sorry for being too wordy, I don't know how to explain this better. I could not find what I am looking for on the internet.

Comment: Create a new, empty repository on Github and it will have the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new empty GitHub repository.

Then go into your local current (say, old-repo) repository. Add a new `remote` (say, `new-repo`) with the URL of new repository.

```
# go into your old repository
$ git remote add new-repo <new-repo-url>

$ git checkout master                            
$ git push new-repo master # now, new-repo 'master' = old-repo 'master' branch
```

If you want to push all branches with commits then use git `all` flag.

```
$ git push new-repo --all
```